# R ggplot2 facet_grid with vars(): how to handle missing argument?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyeval

I want to use tidy evaluation for ggplot's `facet_grid`, but don't know how to allow for missing arguments?

`ggplot2` 3.0.0 introduced the function `vars()` (see [news](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-tidy-evaluation/)), to use tidy
evaluation in for example facet_grid. But it is not clear to me how to handle missing/NULL arguments?

In the following code, how do I do so that no passing any argument to `wrap_by` (i.e. using `p + wrap_by()`) does not return an error?

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, disp)) + geom_point()
wrap_by <- function(...) {
  facet_wrap(vars(...), labeller = label_both)
}
p + wrap_by() #ERROR!
#> Can't subset with `[` using an object of class NULL.
```

Use case:  I want to have a function to define the facet variables, but want to make them optional.

```r
fac_by <- function(var_fac1, var_fac2) {
  facet_grid(rows=vars(!!enquo(var_fac1)), 
             cols=vars(!!enquo(var_fac2)))
}

p+ fac_by(vs, am)
p+ fac_by(var_fac1=vs) # won't work
```

The issue here is that ideally I would allow for either row, either col, both (ideally none also, though this does not seem possible with `facet_grid(NULL, NULL)`)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated, and hopefully this is clearer now?

Comment: Is this fundamentally different? I was hoping vars() could be used with missing, be it a 3 ... or an argument. But indeed, if one has to choose, I need rather specific arguments. Thanks for your help and sorry of that's not so clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
fac_by <- function(var_fac1, var_fac2) {
  # retrieve the arguments from the call
  args_ <- rlang::call_args(match.call())
  # rename them (use na.omit on top of it if you have more arguments)
  names(args_) <- c(var_fac1 = "rows", var_fac2 = "cols")[names(args_)]
  # apply vars on them
  args_ <- purrr::map(args_, vars)
  # build the call
  call_ <- as.call(c(quote(facet_grid),args_))
  eval(call_)
}

p+ fac_by(vs, am)
p+ fac_by(var_fac1=vs)
```

Using `if` and `missing` awould arguably be simpler though :

```
fac_by <- function(var_fac1, var_fac2) {
  facet_grid(rows=if(missing(var_fac1)) NULL else enquos(var_fac1), 
             cols=if(missing(var_fac2)) NULL else enquos(var_fac2))
} 

p+ fac_by(vs, am)
p+ fac_by(var_fac1=vs)
```

Note you can use `enquos(var_fac1)` instead of `vars(!!enquo(var_fac1)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the updated code for `facet_grid` an option would be to pass an expression

```
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)
fac_by <- function(...) {
   e1 <- enexprs(...)   
   do.call(facet_grid, e1)

  }

p + fac_by(rows = vars(vs), cols = vars(am))
```

[image]

```
p + fac_by(rows = vars(vs))
```

[image]

```
p + fac_by(cols = vars(am))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! Ideal solution would avoid the if(), as I am using it actually with a facet_grid, with rows and columns, so code would become quickly cumbersome (check 4 different cases?)?

Comment: @Matifou Can you elaborate on your comment. If you don't wanna pass missing arguments, you ought to check for it. If some functions (I cannot think of any rn, but) handle that, it's because the function by default has that if-statement. Show us that 4 different cases example and we may be able to help.